# Javascript Reg Exp number in brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

```
if (!$is.IE5) {
    v = (ua.toLowerCase().match(new RegExp(".+(?:rv|it|ra|ie)[\\/: ]([\\d.]+)"))||[])[1];
}
```

What does [1] mean in this reg expression??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an **array deference** on the answer.

```
v = (ua.toLowerCase().match(new RegExp(".+(?:rv|it|ra|ie)[\\/: ]([\\d.]+)"))||[])[1];
```

The deference `[1]` is applied to the function result, to get the first matched group (groups are delimited with parentheses `()`).

So `v` = the first group match of `(ua.toLowerCase().match(new RegExp(".+(?:rv|it|ra|ie)[\\/: ]([\\d.]+)"))||[])`.

Note the `||[]` at the end which allows for no matches to not give an error.

This first group match is the `([\\d.]+)` group, the first parentheses is not stored due to the `(?:...)` non-matching group construct.

Comment: first or second as Marcelo said??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: It matches the first matched group, there is only one matched group in this regexp. `[0]` contains the full match given by `.+(?:rv|it|ra|ie)[\\/: ]([\\d.]+)`, `[1]` will contain the matched group `([\\d.]+)`.

Comment: is right. I was testing with regexes that only match the text of interest.

Comment: An equivalent regexp (from the point of view of grouping) shown up in Chrome Console: http://i.imgur.com/ocrSZ.jpg